# split, transpose and gather data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, transpose

I need to  gather and transpose the data in data frame, hourly values should be in one column. First column should be date with hour and second transposed hourly values.

Sample of data:

```
    structure(list(Year = c(2016L, 2016L), JDay = 1:2, Hour_1 = c(2.59, 
5.95), Hour_2 = c(2.19, 5.84), Hour_3 = c(1.84, 5.75), Hour_4 = c(1.51, 
5.66), Hour_5 = c(1.21, 5.58), Hour_6 = c(0.94, 5.5), Hour_7 = c(0.69, 
5.43), Hour_8 = c(0.45, 5.37), Hour_9 = c(0.23, 5.31), Hour_10 = c(2.18, 
6.19), Hour_11 = c(4.39, 7.16), Hour_12 = c(6.29, 8), Hour_13 = c(7.76, 
8.65), Hour_14 = c(8.68, 9.06), Hour_15 = c(9, 9.2), Hour_16 = c(8.68, 
9.06), Hour_17 = c(7.76, 8.65), Hour_18 = c(7.8, 8.52), Hour_19 = c(7.21, 
7.57), Hour_20 = c(6.85, 6.99), Hour_21 = c(6.59, 6.57), Hour_22 = c(6.39, 
6.25), Hour_23 = c(6.22, 5.98), Hour_24 = c(6.08, 5.75)), .Names = c("Year", 
"JDay", "Hour_1", "Hour_2", "Hour_3", "Hour_4", "Hour_5", "Hour_6", 
"Hour_7", "Hour_8", "Hour_9", "Hour_10", "Hour_11", "Hour_12", 
"Hour_13", "Hour_14", "Hour_15", "Hour_16", "Hour_17", "Hour_18", 
"Hour_19", "Hour_20", "Hour_21", "Hour_22", "Hour_23", "Hour_24"
), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
```

Use of gather is just giving me all Hour_1 values in in order...

```
gather(OP_daily[, c(5:28)], time,temp, Hour_1:Hour_24)
```

Example output:

```
date           temp    
2016-1-1 1:00  2.59
2016-1-1 2:00  2.19
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sound like the `gather` your are looking for:

```
df %>%
  gather(-c(Year,JDay), key = "Hour", value = "temp") %>%
  unite(date,Year,JDay,Hour) %>%
  mutate(date=as.POSIXct(date,format='%Y_%j_Hour_%H'))  %>%
  arrange(date)

                  date     temp
                <time>    <dbl>
1  2016-01-01 01:00:00 2.592221
2  2016-01-01 02:00:00 2.193009
3  2016-01-01 03:00:00 1.835225
4  2016-01-01 04:00:00 1.511071
5  2016-01-01 05:00:00 1.214767
6  2016-01-01 06:00:00 0.941902
```

**EDIT**

To see how many observations per day:

```
res <- df %>%
  gather(-c(Year,JDay), key = "Hour", value = "temp") %>%
  unite(date,Year,JDay,Hour) %>%
  mutate(date=as.POSIXct(date,format='%Y_%j_Hour_%H',tz = "GMT"))  %>%
  arrange(date)
res%>%
mutate(date_only=as.Date(date))%>%
group_by(date_only)%>%
summarise(count=n())

   date_only count
      <date> <int>
1 2016-01-01    23
2 2016-01-02    24
3 2016-01-03     1
```

Comment: Thank you @P Lapointe , but I need to transpose every row containing hourly into one day, and so on. Hours from 1:24 are first day and so on.

Comment: @m_c Can you add the required result as a table in your question?

Comment: just did, seen that it was not clear enough. your solution gives me something like my code above, which is why I am posting a question here.

Comment: @Not sure. I added a bit of code for you to inspect how many data points you have per day. It is normal that day 1 has 23 items as 24:00 is also 00:00. Check for days with more than 24 data points.

Comment: solved it. I had another columns in data sed that I did not show with example data set, my fault, but I was already brainwashed last night. thanks again.